# webSql select query error

Tags: android, cordova

In developing in PhoneGap for Android, I'm trying to store data in database and want to retrieve it, and during the select query I am getting errors: the `.code` will be zero and the `.message` will be `"the statement callback raised an exception or statement error callback did not return false"`. Sometimes both `message` and `code` are undefined.

In my code below I am mentioning where I am getting error. Otherwise all is working fine. I think my `usy` call back function I solved the synchronous problem so please I think some syntax error. Sometimes it calls my success method and there it shows length is not undefined.

```
$scope.data_for_net=function(check){
//var db = window.openDatabase("JiyoNatural", "1.0", "JiyoNatural", 200000);
    var today=new Date();

     var dd=today.getDate();

     var mm=today.getMonth()+1;

     var yyyy=today.getFullYear();

     if(dd<10) {

         dd='0'+dd;

     } 

    if(mm<10) {

        mm='0'+mm;

        } 

     today = yyyy+'-'+mm+'-'+dd;    

      todayDate=today.toString();


    db.transaction(function(tx){



            var query='SELECT * FROM Recipe WHERE Recipe_Date=?,Recipe_meal_Type=?';


            //var sql_query='select * from Recipe where Recipe_Date="'+todayDate+'" and Recipe_meal_Type="+Lunch"'

            // tx.executeSql('select * from Recipe where Recipe_Date=?,Recipe_meal_Type=?;', [todayDate]["Lunch"], $scope.query_data_fatch_for_lunch, $scope.transaction_error);//here i am getting error

             tx.executeSql(query, [todayDate],['Lunch'], $scope.query_data_fatch_for_lunch, $scope.transaction_error);

         });
   }

    }   

//this is my method

$scope.query_data_fatch_for_lunch=function(tx,result){

console.log("data_fatch_for_lunch is calling");

var RecipeInfo=[];

var recipe={};

var rowData=[];

for(var i=0;i<result.rows.length;i++){

    var meal_type=result.rows.item(i).Recipe_meal_Type;

    var recipe_item=result.rows.item(i).Recipe_Name;

    console.log(recipe_item);

    var energy=result.rows.item(i).Recipe_energy;

    var carbohydrate=result.rows.item(i).Recipe_corbohydrates;

    var protein=result.rows.item(i).Recipe_protein;

    var fat=result.rows.item(i).Recipe_fat;

    rowdata.push(recipe_item);

    rowdata.push(energy);

    rowdata.push(carbohydrate);

    rowdata.push(protein);

    rowdata.push(fat);

    console.log("data is successfull add");

}

recipe.itemInfo=rowdata;

recipe.itemType=meal_type;

RecipeInfo.push(recipe);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are pretty close although I haven't tested the above code very thoroughly... 
But `tx.executeSql(query, [todayDate],['Lunch'], $scope.query_data_fatch_for_lunch, $scope.transaction_error);` line seems a bit weird.

Can you replace `[todayDate],['Lunch']` with **[todayDate, 'Lunch']**?
Because that is the way the parameters work.

Comment: Also the where clause is not logically correct `WHERE Recipe_Date=?,Recipe_meal_Type=?';`. There should be an OR or AND operator like  `WHERE Recipe_Date=? AND/OR Recipe_meal_Type=?';` depending upon his requirement.

Comment: how to tell thank you i don`t know...it`s from my heart thank you so much for help.